# HTML/CSS Can't get form and buttons to work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

For a school assignment I have to create a "Doughnut/Coffee Shop", in which I used HTML and CSS, but I can't seem to get my "Calculate Totals" and "Reset Form" buttons for my form to work.

Sorry for formatting but here is my HTML:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xJ8SkqQ4

And my CSS:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zZbpt61Y

If anyone could find my error(s) I'd greatly appreciate it.

Edit: Such a stupid mistake, I forgot my id on my select dropdown bar. Thank you again Austin Greco!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please include your code in the question it self. You will get more and quicker responses that way. Alos let me you can format code wit the `{}` button in the editor or do a full "pastebin" stye example with the `<>` button

Comment: You can also try your code out on jsfiddle or similar site to experiment with it.

Comment: If you're using Firefox, install the Firebug extension and check the console. If you're using Chrome, just open the console by hitting Ctrl + Shift + J. Personally I prefer Firebug, as its error message are more helpful. In this case, the first error it comes up with is that DoughnutChoice is null. That would be because you've stated it should be the value of #DoughnutChoiceField, which does not exist. Try that...I think you'll have more debugging to do so get Firebug up and running.

Answer (score 1):

You were just missing the id on the doughnut `select`:

```
<select id="DoughnutChoiceField">
```

If you use the chrome/ff debugger, you can debug and see the element is null, which means `document.getElementById` failed to find the id.

```js
function ResetForm()
    {
    document.getElementById("OrderForm").reset(); 
    }
   
   function ValidateNumber(value)
    {//We need to ensure that what you entered is a valid number
    if (isNaN(value))
     alert("What you entered is not a number. You entered a " + value +".")
    }

   function PlaceOrder()
    {
    const TAXRATE = 0.087;
    
    // Coffee blend constant prices
    const HOUSEBLENDPRICE = 8.00;
    const KENYAPRICE = 9.50;
    const BOURBONPRICE = 12.00;
    const NOBLENDPRICE = 0.00;
    
    // Coffee size constant prices
    const SMALLSIZEPRICE = 0.50;
    const MEDIUMSIZEPRICE = 0.75;
    const LARGESIZEPRICE = 1.00;
    const NOSIZEPRICE = 0.00;
    
    // Doughnut type constant prices
    const GLAZEDDOUGHNUTPRICE = 1.00;
    const CHOCOLATEDOUGHNUTPRICE = 1.50;
    const MAPLEDOUGHNUTPRICE = 1.50;
    const NOTYPEPRICE = 0.00;
    
    // Coffee Amount
    var NumberOfBags = parseInt(document.getElementById("NoBagsField").value);
    if (isNaN(NumberOfBags))
     {// if no entry, then set it to zero in the form
     NumberOfBags = 0;
     document.getElementById("NoBagsField").value = 0;
     }
    
    // Coffee Blend
    var BeanChoice = document.getElementById("CoffeeBlendField");
    var Blend = BeanChoice.options[BeanChoice.selectedIndex].value;
    if (Blend == "HouseBlend")
     {BeanPrice = HOUSEBLENDPRICE;}
    if (Blend == "KenianBlend")
     {BeanPrice = KENYAPRICE;}
    if (Blend == "BourbonBlend")
     {BeanPrice = BOURBONPRICE;}
    if (Blend == "NoBlend")
     {BeanPrice = NOBLENDPRICE;}
    
    // Price for Coffee Size
    var SizeChoice = document.getElementById("SizeChoiceField");
    var Size = SizeChoice.options[SizeChoice.selectedIndex].value;
    if (Size == "SmallSize")
     {SizePrice = SMALLSIZEPRICE;}
    if (Size == "MediumSize")
     {SizePrice = MEDIUMSIZEPRICE;}
    if (Size == "LargeSize")
     {SizePrice = LARGESIZEPRICE;}
    if (Size == "NoSize")
     {SizePrice = NOSIZEPRICE;}
     
    // Type of Doughnut
    var DoughnutChoice = document.getElementById("DoughnutChoiceField");
    var Doughnut = DoughnutChoice.options[DoughnutChoice.selectedIndex].value;
    if (Doughnut == "Glazed")
     {DoughnutPrice = GLAZEDDOUGHNUTPRICE;}
    if (Doughnut == "Chocolate")
     {DoughnutPrice = CHOCOLATEDOUGHNUTPRICE;}
    if (Doughnut == "Maple")
     {DoughnutPrice = MAPLEDOUGHNUTPRICE;}
    if (Doughnut == "NoDoughnut")
     {DoughnutPrice = NOTYPEPRICE;}
    
    // Doughnut Amount
    var NumberOfDoughnuts = parseInt(document.getElementById("DoughnutAmountField").value);
    if (isNaN(NumberOfDoughnuts))
     {// if no entry, then set it to zero in the form
     NumberOfDoughnuts = 0;
     document.getElementById("DoughnutAmountField").value = 0;
     }
    
    // Pricing
    var SubTotal = (((BeanPrice+SizePrice)*NumberOfBags) + ((DoughnutPrice)*NumberOfDoughnuts));
    var SalesTax = SubTotal * TAXRATE;
    var Total = SubTotal + SalesTax;
    document.getElementById("SubTotalField").value = "$" + SubTotal.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("SalesTaxField").value = "$" + SalesTax.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("TotalField").value = "$" + Total.toFixed(2);
    }
```

```css
.body
{

}
.header
{
 font-size: 25px;
 top:10px;
 left:100px;
 width:900px;
 height:150px; 
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #9A0E2A;
 border-width: 5px;
 display: table;
 color: yellow;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
.header h1
{
 color: #AE5AAB;
 text-align: center;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.flipimage
{
 -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}


.MainBody
{
    width: 800px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.left
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-color: #9A0E2A;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 color: yellow;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
.left img
{
 position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.left h1
{
    color: DarkCyan;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 15px;
}
.left h2
{
    color: DarkCyan;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 20px;
 margin-left: 15px;
}
.left h3
{
    color: White;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 15px;
 margin-left: 15px;
}


.center
{
 position: absolute;
    width: 650px;
    border-style: solid;
 border-color: #9A0E2A;
 border-width: 5px; 
    margin-left: 250px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 600px;
 color: yellow;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
.center h1
{
    color: RoyalBlue;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 100px;
}

.center p
{
 color: RoyalBlue;
 text-indent:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainBody">
     </div>
     
     <div class="header">
     <img src="doughnut3.png" align="left" width="300px" height="150px">
     <h1>Doughnut Shop</h1>
     <img src="doughnut3.png" align="right" class="flipimage" width="300px" height="150px">
     </div>
     
     <div class="left">
     <h1 valign="top" align="left">Shop Address:</h1>
     <h3 valign="top" align="left">12345 E. Main Street</h3>
     <h2 valign="top" align="left">Phone:</h2>
     <h3 valign="top" align="left">(509) 123-4567</h3>
     <h2 valign="top" align="left">Email:</h2>
     <h3 valign="top" align="left">doughnutshop@hotmail.com</h3>

     
     
     <hr>
     <img valign="bottom" src="doughnut.png" width="250px" height="175px">

     
     </div>


     <div class="center">
     <h1>Order:</h1>
     
     
     
      
     <p><b>Customer Name:</b>
      <input type="text" name="state" value=""><br>
     </p>
     <p><b>Order Date:</b>
      <input type="date" name="date">
     </p>
     <hr>
     <form id="OrderForm">
     <p><b>Coffee Blend</b> 
      <select id="CoffeeBlendField">
       <option value="NoBlend" disabled selected style='display:none;'></option>
       <option value="HouseBlend">House Blend</option>
       <option value="KenianBlend">Kenian Blend</option>
       <option value="BourbonBlend">Bourbon Blend</option>
      </select>
     </p>
     
     <p><b>Coffee Size:</b>
      <select id="SizeChoiceField">
       <option value="NoSize" disabled selected style='display:none;'></option>
       <option value="SmallSize">Small</option>
       <option value="MediumSize">Medium</option>
       <option value="LargeSize">Large</option>
       
      </select>
     </p>
     

     <p><b>Quantity (1-20):</b>
      <input type="text"
        id="NoBagsField"
        placeholder="#"
        value=""
        size = "1"
        onblur="ValidateNumber(this.value)">
      </p>
        
    
     <hr>
     <p><b>Doughnut Type:</b>
      <select id="DoughnutChoiceField">
       <option value="NoDoughnut" disabled selected style='display:none;'></option>
       <option value="Glazed">Glazed</option>
       <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
       <option value="Maple">Maple</option>
      </select>
     </p>
     
     <p><b>Quantity (1-20):</b>
      <input type="text"
        id="DoughnutAmountField"
        placeholder="#"
        value=""
        size = "1"
        onblur="ValidateNumber(this.value)">
     </p>
     <hr>
     <p><b>SubTotal:</b>
      <input type="text"
        id="SubTotalField"
        value="">
     </p>
       
     <p><b>SalesTax:</b>
     <input type="text"
       id="SalesTaxField"
       value="">
     </p>
       
     <p><b>Total Sale:</b>
     <input type="text"
       id="TotalField"
         value="">
     </p>
     </form>
     <button onclick="PlaceOrder()">Calculate Totals</button>
     <button onclick="ResetForm()">Reset</button>

     </div>
```

Comment: Oh my god I feel so stupid. Thank you so much!! You are my savior, lol.